Why does isnan() sometimes slowdown badly on ICX compiler?
I found a slowdown quirk on the Intel ICX compiler 2023 which goes some way to explaining my peculiar benchmark timings reported in earlier questions. I have what and how but don't understand why the code it generates is so slow. This is a simpler MRE using Horner polynomial evaluation of cubics. I think it is now fully reproducible on ICX.
I was taught and still believe that cache locality is a good thing when evaluating polynomial coefficients. I recently noticed that MS coefficient tables for sin, cos were in block order rather than sequential by usage and wondered what effect shuffling them into order of use would have. The answer on the MS compiler was ~1s faster but on the Intel compiler it was a disastrous 4x slowdown. Not as big as some I have seen but big enough to be very obvious. This one seems robust and shows up executing in any DOS window not just inside the debugger. It requires a larger MRE than I would like but this code is as small as I can make it and still show the errant behaviour. It is a clear code generator defect.
I am testing the performance of computing a cubic polynomial approximation for exp(x) with the coefficients stored in the two most commonly used configurations:
 a00, a01, a02,...a0N, a10, a11,... a1N, a20, a21,...a2N, a30,a31,.. a3N (stride = N)
 vs
 b00, b10, b20, b30, b10, b11, b12, b13, b20,... b0N, b1N, b2N, b3N (stride = 1)

 for comparison I also created 2 arrays c and d with the same data in as a and b.

 The key expressions being tested are:
 return a0[i]   + x * (a1[i]    + x * (a2[i]    + x * a3[i]));
 return b[j]    + x * (b[j + 1] + x * (b[j + 2] + x*b[j+3]) );
 return c[0][i] + x * (c[1][i]  + x * (c[2][i]  + x * c[3][i]));
 return d[i][0] + x * (d[i][1]  + x * (d[i][2]  + x * d[i][3]));

This is close to but not identical to how some MS library code works. Here is the MRE:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <math.h>

// Sweep floats from 0 to 1 in steps of 1/2^32 and compute integral
// all arguments and function evaluations finite - no denorms and no infinities

#define N2 64


double a0[N2+1], a1[N2 + 1], a2[N2 + 1], a3[N2 + 1], b[4 * N2 + 4];
double c[4][N2 + 1], d[N2 + 1][4];

const double exp_fac = exp(1.0 / N2);
const double x_step = 1.0 / N2;

const double exp_coeff[] = { 1.0, 1.000000004959292957551545820, 0.4999942680271538875, 0.16764564801933203 };
void init()
{
    int i, j;
    double exp_val;
    exp_val = 1.0;
    j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= N2; i++)
    {
        d[i][0] = c[0][i] = b[j++] = a0[i] = exp_val;
        d[i][1] = c[1][i] = b[j++] = a1[i] = exp_val * exp_coeff[1];
        d[i][2] = c[2][i] = b[j++] = a2[i] = exp_val * exp_coeff[2];
        d[i][3] = c[3][i] = b[j++] = a3[i] = exp_val * exp_coeff[3];
        exp_val *= exp_fac;
    }
}

double my_exp_Ha(double x)
{
    int i = (int)(x * N2 );
    x = x - i*x_step;
    return a0[i] + x * (a1[i] + x * (a2[i] + x * a3[i]));
}

double my_exp_Hb(double x)
{
    int i = (int)(x * N2);
    x = x - i * x_step;
    i *= 4;
    return b[i] + x * (b[i + 1] + x * (b[i + 2] + x*b[i+3]) );
}

double my_exp_Hc(double x)
{
    int i = (int)(x * N2);
    x = x - i * x_step;
    return c[0][i] + x * (c[1][i] + x * (c[2][i] + x * c[3][i]));
}

double my_exp_Hd(double x)
{
    int i = (int)(x * N2);
    x = x - i * x_step;
    return d[i][0] + x * (d[i][1]+ x * (d[i][2]+ x * d[i][3]));
}

double my_exp_Eb(double x)
{
    int i = (int)(x * N2);
    double y, z, x2;
    x = x - i * x_step;
    i *= 4;
    return b[i] + x * b[i + 1] + x * x * (b[i + 2] + x * b[i + 3]);
}

double my_exp_Rb_helper(double x, double* b_i, int n)
{
    if (!n) return b_i[0];
    return b_i[0] + x * my_exp_Rb_helper(x, b_i + 1, n - 1);
}

double my_exp_Rb(double x)
{   // recursive version to maximise number of call-ret in evaluation
    int i = (int)(x * N2);
    x = x - i * x_step;
    i *= 4;
    return my_exp_Rb_helper(x, b+i, 3);
}


double my_exp_Qb_helper(double x, double* b_i)
{   // summed in normal way
    int i;
    double xi[4], val = b_i[3];
    xi[1] = x;
    for (i = 2; i < 4; i++)
    {
        xi[i] = xi[i - 1] * x;
    }
    val = b_i[3] * xi[3];
    for (i = 2; i > 0; i--)
        val += xi[i] * b_i[i];
    return b_i[0]+val;
}

double my_exp_Qb(double x)
{   // monomial evaluation and sum last to first
    int i = (int)(x * N2);
    x = x - i * x_step;
    return my_exp_Qb_helper(x, b + 4*i);
}

double my_exp_Zb(double x)
{   // computed in the least accurate method
    int j, i = (int)(x * N2);
    double val, xn;
    x = x - i * x_step;
    i *= 4;
    val = b[i++];
    xn = x;
    for (j = 1; j < 4; j++)
    {
        val += xn * b[i++];
        xn *= x;
    }
    return val;
}

void timefun(const char* name, double (*test_fun)(double)) //, bool verbose)
{
    // simple minded integration of test_fun for timing purposes

    uint32_t argi, j;
    uint64_t t = 0;
    double arg, arginc, res, sum;
    time_t start, end;
    printf("\nTiming %s\n", name);
    argi = 0;
    sum = 0.0;
    arg = 0x1.0p-100; // so that log won't object
    arginc = 1.0 / (0x1.p+32 - 1.0);
    start = clock();
    do {
        res = (*test_fun)(arg);
//       _mm_mfence();
//        t = __rdtsc();        // force compete pipeline stall until empty
        if (!isnan(res))        // this test for nans seems to be implicated
            sum += res;
        argi++; // sequential
        arg = argi * arginc;
        if ((argi & 0x3ffffff) == 0) printf(".");
    } while (argi);
    end = clock();
    sum = sum / (0x1.p+32 - 1.0);  // adding this normalisation line makes it run full speed
    printf("\ntime taken %6.2f %x sum = %18.14g\n", (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, (uint32_t) (t>>32), sum);
}

void test_fun(const char* name, double (*fun)(double), double x)
{
    printf("%s(%.1g) =\t%-18.14g\n", name, x, (*fun)(x));
}

int main(void)
{    
    init();                       

    test_fun("exp", my_exp_Ha, 1.0);
    test_fun("exp", my_exp_Ha, 0.5);
 
    timefun("Horner a exp_Ha", my_exp_Ha);   // original MS style coeffs a0,a1..aN,b0,b1..bN,c0..cN, d0..dN
    timefun("Horner b exp_Hb", my_exp_Hb);   // this line misbehaves won't inline a0,b0,c0,d0,a1,b1...cN,dN
    timefun("Horner c exp_Hc", my_exp_Hc);   // 2D array same layout as "a"
    timefun("Horner d exp_Hd", my_exp_Hd);   // 2D array same layout as "b"

    timefun("Estrin b exp_Eb", my_exp_Eb);   // these are needed to force Horner b not to inline IDKW
    timefun("Brute1 b exp_Zb", my_exp_Zb);   // comment any one out and Horner b will inline and work OK
    timefun("Brute2 b exp_Qb", my_exp_Qb);
    timefun("Recurs b exp_Rb", my_exp_Rb);

    return 0;  
}

I had expected the b form to be very slightly faster on a sequential benchmark summing f(x) on 0 to 1.0 due to cache locality. The result which should be e-1 is printed out as a check. MSC aces this test. ICX has difficulty with the stride 1 coefficients in a single 1D array.
The timing results on ICX are interesting (all times in seconds on Intel compiler apart from the first column which is MSC for reference).



Benchmark
MSC 17.1 isnan()
Intel Inline
No test
isnan()
nan+sfence
nan+lfence
nan+rdtsc
nan+mfence




Horner a
7.5
Y
6.4
8.5
8.5
50.6
53.0
72.6


Horner b
6.5
N
6.4
31.5
31.8
52.7
53.8
74.0


Horner c
6.3
Y
6.3
8.3
8.2
50.6
53.6
72.5


Horner d
6.7
Y
6.3
8.7
8.6
50.6
53.6
73.8


Horner Rb
19.3
N
12.8
27.3
26.9
63.4
65.6
103.6



As an aside I don't understand why mfence is slower than rdtsc either.
Optimisations are at maximum. MS compiler agrees with my expectations. Intel doesn't. On the plus side Intel generates faster recursive code than MS. ICX Compiler options under MSC IDE are:
/GS /W3 /Qxalderlake /Gy /Zi /O2 /Ob2 /fp:fast /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Qipo /Zc:forScope /arch:CORE-AVX2 /Oi /MD /Fa"x64\Release" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release" //fprofile-instr-use "x64\Release" /Ot /Fp"x64\Release\SO_toy7.pch"
The first Intel problem is that it refuses to inline the code for Horner b. The second is that due to a clunky isnan() function it creates an sfence pipeline stall slamming the result onto the stack and testing longhand in classic register arithmetic. Then to compound things it makes a very poor fist of the conditional add.
The ICX code generated when the function is evaluated inline is as follows
 sum += res;
 00007FF6EFAD13F0  vaddsd      xmm6,xmm0,xmm6
 argi++; // sequential
     arg = argi * arginc  
 00007FF6EFAD13F4  mov         eax,ebp  
 00007FF6EFAD13F6  vcvtsi2sd   xmm0,xmm12,rax  
 00007FF6EFAD13FB  vmulsd      xmm7,xmm10,xmm0
 if ((argi & 0x3ffffff) == 0) printf(".");  
 00007FF6EFAD13FF  test        ebp,3FFFFFFh  
 00007FF6EFAD1405  je          main+380h (07FF6EFAD1460h)  
 00007FF6EFAD1407  inc         ebp  
 do {
      res = (*test_fun)(arg);
 00007FF6EFAD1409  vmulsd      xmm0,xmm8,xmm7  
 00007FF6EFAD140D  vcvttsd2si  eax,xmm0  
 00007FF6EFAD1411  vroundsd    xmm0,xmm0,xmm0,0Bh  
 00007FF6EFAD1417  vfmadd132sd xmm0,xmm7,xmm9  
 00007FF6EFAD141C  shl         eax,2  
 00007FF6EFAD141F  cdqe  
 00007FF6EFAD1421  vmovsd      xmm7,qword ptr [rbx+rax*8+18h]  
 00007FF6EFAD1427  vfmadd213sd xmm7,xmm0,mmword ptr [rbx+rax*8+10h]  
 00007FF6EFAD142E  vfmadd213sd xmm7,xmm0,mmword ptr [rbx+rax*8+8]  
 00007FF6EFAD1435  vfmadd213sd xmm7,xmm0,mmword ptr [rbx+rax*8]  
     if (!isnan(res)) sum += res;       // this test for nans seems to be implicated
 00007FF6EFAD143B  vmovsd      qword ptr [rsp+30h],xmm7  
 00007FF6EFAD1441  mov         rcx,rdi  
 00007FF6EFAD1444  call        r12         ## isnan() test - doesn't stall pipeline
 00007FF6EFAD1447  vmovapd     xmm0,xmm11  ## xmm11 contains -0.0
 00007FF6EFAD144B  cmp         ax,2  
 00007FF6EFAD144F  je          main+310h (07FF6EFAD13F0h)  
 00007FF6EFAD1451  vmovapd     xmm0,xmm7   ## result of function
 00007FF6EFAD1455  jmp         main+310h (07FF6EFAD13F0h)  

The code generated when the function is evaluated by calling the function my_exp_Hb is below (register mappings and stack usage are different but the structure is the same
  do {
      res = (*test_fun)(arg);
00007FF724B511D9  vmovapd     xmm0,xmm6  
00007FF724B511DD  call        rsi          ## my_exp_Hb() xmm0 input and return value
00007FF724B511DF  vmovapd     xmm6,xmm0  
      if (!isnan(res))        // this test for nans seems to be implicated
00007FF724B511E3  vmovsd      qword ptr [rsp+20h],xmm0  
00007FF724B511E9  mov         rcx,rbx  
00007FF724B511EC  call        rdi          ## pipeline stalls here loading from stack
00007FF724B511EE  vmovapd     xmm0,xmm8    ## xmm8 contains -0.0
00007FF724B511F2  cmp         ax,2  
00007FF724B511F6  je          timefun+80h (07FF724B511C0h)  
00007FF724B511F8  vmovapd     xmm0,xmm6    ## result of function
00007FF724B511FC  jmp         timefun+80h (07FF724B511C0h)  

Comparing the code (438-444) in the inline version and (1E3-1EC) are essentially identical apart from the register mapping (which I don't believe makes a difference). I'm inclined to blame vmovapd     xmm6,xmm0 for the sluggishness of the second  method but I don't understand why this should be! My simplistic view is that the ret should do not harm.
I tested this by making a recursive version of my_exp_Rb which by using recursion is over 2x slower and the Intel handles that much better than MSC (in favourable cases). It is about 30% faster than the crippled my_exp_Hb code.
The code generated for isnan() is most unfortunate and the way that the ICX compiler has implemented the conditional add is risible (11EE-11FC). The neatest solution being on the assumption that most values will not be nans so that should be the fastest path and just skip the addition on the rare occaissions that a nan is encountered.
sum += res;
00007FF6EFAD13F0  vaddsd      xmm6,xmm0,xmm6 
00007FF6EFAD13F4  mov         eax,ebp     
...
00007FF6EFAD144B  cmp         ax,2  
00007FF6EFAD144F  jne         main+310h (07FF6EFAD13F0h)  ## OK path fastest
00007FF6EFAD1455  jmp         main+314h (07FF6EFAD13F4h)  ## nan path skip add 

I can now see what is happening and provoke it almost to order. I understand how it occurs. The code for isnan stalls in the non-inline code effectively an sfence occurs.
I do not understand at all why this happens. My simple minded view is that when the function is evaluated by the inline version it should be more at risk of this happening. I guess there must be something about return instructions that blindsides speculative execution. I'd like to understand this failure better to avoid it in the future.
MSC 17.1 doesn't inline so it is more compact and doesn't have the problem at all since it cleanly inlines the nan test as the following very concise SIMD code (it is 25% faster too):
       res = (*test_fun)(arg);
00007FF7AC1B17F2  vmovaps     xmm0,xmm7  
00007FF7AC1B17F6  call        rdi        ## my_exp_Hb() xmm0 input and return value

       if (!isnan(res))        // this test for nans seems to be implicated
00007FF7AC1B17F8  vucomisd    xmm0,xmm0  
00007FF7AC1B17FC  setp        al  
00007FF7AC1B17FF  cmp         al,1  
00007FF7AC1B1801  je          timefun+67h (07FF7AC1B1807h)  
           sum += res;
00007FF7AC1B1803  vaddsd      xmm6,xmm6,xmm0  
       argi++; // sequential
00007FF7AC1B1807  inc         ebx  

An altogether much more elegant formulation.

That looks like compiler options for MSVC and not for ICX?

I'm using Intel ICX integrated inside the MSVC environment on Win11. I can switch between those two compilers with the same source code very easily in that (single click). Snag is that it displays the ICX command line options in MS DOS command line form. At least I think it does. Do any stand out as not being ICX options?

Plenty of them? /Zi, /Zc and so on. So the question is what actual compiler options that are passed to the compiler.

@Lundin interesting. I'd never really noticed that until now. It just worked. Usually the Intel ICX compiler beats MSC 17.1 hands down for me at higher optimisations since its intrinsic function library is better. I was somewhat surprised that it had such a hard time with polynomials. The core of my question remains though - why is call rsi instead of inline evaluation of the function so damaging to performance here. That is a CPU architecture quirk rather than compiler options.

Well if you are running with optimizations enabled on MSVC but disabled at ICX, then that would probably explain a lot. I think someone who's an expert on whatever IDE you are using (Visual Studio?) better answer this.

@lundin I'm pretty sure ICX is optimising at about the same level as MSC most of the time. It is rather more inclined to inline stuff than MSC but for me at least usually ICX produces measurably faster code (except  in this particular instance).  Notably ICX does a lot better with recursion for example (as shown above).

How can it though? It seems that you've handed it a bunch of target-specific options for MSVC which it has no idea what to do with.

@Lundin I haven't done anything. That is what the MSVC IDE tells me the command line it used was. I will try it with an explicit command line when I get a chance.  I have put it on Godbolt and so discovered that ICX requires "immintrin.h" rather than "intrin.h" to use AVX2 code for isnan(). That fixes the slowdown wonderfully. That is with -O3 -mfma -Winline Thanks for the pointer I now know why ICX generated that clunky isnan() code, but not why it had such a profound tarpit effect when a function return was involved.
